# ListView resizing after show up keyboard

Tags: flutter, dart

After creating the SearchDelegate class buildSuggestions widget while the keyboard shows up in ListView.build, it shrinks. How can I fix ListView to full height widget.

Code:

```
Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
recentList = getResponse(context);
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: recentList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      SearchedCase object = recentList[index];
      print(object);
      return _listTileResult(context, object);
    }
  );}
```

[gif showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADkhi.gif)

Comment: Did you tried shrinkWrap with true??

Comment: @asn21 yes, same result

Answer (score 0):

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  ...
)
```

Comment: What are you running it on? Have you tried another device/emulator?